# react-md SelectField onChange not updating properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

I'm using the `'react-md'` library and I am trying to use the `SelectField` component, but when I send a function for `onChange` the select field no longer updates as it's supposed to.

```
handleSelection = (value, index, event, details) => {
  // "details.id" is the id of the field which I am using to keep track of state  
  this.setState({[details.id]: value});
}

render() {
  const STRING_SELECTORS = ['At most', 'At least'];

  return(
  <div>
   <SelectField
     id="calories-selector"
     className="md-cell selector md-cell--5"
     menuItems={STRING_SELECTORS}
     defaultValue="At most"
     onChange={this.handleSelection)
   />
  )
}
```

When I don't call `this.setState()` in the `handleSelection` function, the menu changes as expected when clicking an item, however when I do call setState, it updates the selection on a delay. If the menu says "At most" and I click "At least" it will stay at "At most" then if I click "At most" it will *then* change the "At least".

I've had a similar issue with input fields, and to solve this I used `onBlur` instead of `onChange`, but the `react-md` library's `onBlur` doesn't get triggered in the way that I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value prop of `SelectField` component. Create a state and bind it to the `SelectField` value prop and update the state at `onChange` event to the selected value.

Comment: How do I bind a state to the value prop of "SelectField"?